# float precision problem in mysql

Tags: mysql, types, floating-point, double

Can anybody, given example below, make to me an explanation how FLOAT works in mySQL? I know that float is approximative, but really, such a difference? And there is only 9 digits, so it is not overflow problem, isn't it?

```
mysql> create table t(f FLOAT(15,2), db DOUBLE);
mysql> insert into t(f,db) VALUES (512659663, 512659663);
mysql> select * from t;

+--------------+-----------+
| f            | db        |
+--------------+-----------+
| 512659648.00 | 512659663 |
+--------------+-----------+
```

(mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.44, for Win32 (ia32) on Windows XP)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`FLOAT` is a `32`-bit type with, as the name suggests, floating point. The higher is the value, the less is the absolute precision.

`512659648` is large enough to introduce errors in tens.

`Update:`

In `IEEE-754` (that's what `FLOAT` is), the data are stored in `32` bits: `1`-bit sign, `8`-bit binary exponent and `23`-bit significand.

The exponent shows you the closest least power of `2` (`28` in your case, or `268435456`).

The significand is a binary fraction. It can store numbers from `1` to `2` with precision up to `2^-23`. In your case, it's `1.11101000111010010000110`, or `~ 1.9098060` in decimal notation.

The number is calculated as a product of the exponent and the significand.

Given all this, precision is `2 ^ (28 - 23) = 2 ^ 5 = 32` for the numbers of that order (`2^28` to `2^29`).

Comment: Is there possible to estimate approximation error? It depends linear on number's size or there is something else?

Comment: @ts : 32-bit IEEE 754 floating point numbers can hold about 7 decimal digits of accuracy; 64-bit ones can hold about 16 decimal digits.  Anything beyond 7 digits is going to run into problems.  The FLOAT(15,2) qualifier is more wishful thinking than effective; the (15,2) is basically ignored.

Comment: @Jonathan: the `,2` part will be regarded for the lesser values, while `15` will be for the greater ones.

Comment: Does that mean you won't be allowed to store a value with absolute value smaller than 0.01 and greater than 0.00, nor of absolute value of 10^13 or larger?  If so, then the qualifier has some teeth to it, but expecting 15 digits of accuracy from a 32-bit float is still wishing for the moon.

Comment: @Jonathan: you can insert values as small as you want, but they will be rounded to the closest `0.01` (and then converted into `IEEE`). The values greater than `10^14 - 1` won't make it indeed. `15` digits are not the digits of accuracy but rather digits of decimal representation of the most accurate approximation possible.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in MySQL, FLOAT and DOUBLE are both approximate floating-point numbers.  [MySQL uses four bytes for single-precision values and eight bytes for double-precision values.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html)

So, **both columns are approximate** - it's just that your FLOAT column only gets 4 bytes to try to approximate your number.

Comment: I am reading the documentation, it says, if we specify float(24) or more it becomes 8 bytes, does that make it the same as double ??

Answer (score 1):

The mantissa of a single precision floating point number is 22 bits in length.  It therefore cannot accurately store an integer number greater than 2^22, 4194304.

Comment: IEEE 754 has an implied 1-bit at the start of the mantissa, effectively adding 1-bit.  There is a sign bit, an 8-bit exponent, and 23+1 bits in the mantissa for a 32-bit number.  See: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) or [General Decimal Arithmetic](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/).